# MacOS files to NAS with rsync --iconv repeats the sync over and over

Tags: rsync, macos, character-encoding

According to [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643402/convert-unicode-decomposition-when-transferring-files-to-web-server/25767659#25767659) and similar advice I am using the `--iconv` option in `rsync` (version 3.2.7) to sync file with umlauts (`ä` `ü` `ö` ...) to my Synology NAS. However the `--iconv` option does not work as expected:

```
rsync -vaN --delete --iconv=utf8-mac,utf8 Mac_folder/ NAS_folder/
```

works but when repeating the command the copy process starts over and over for **every file and folder with umlauts**

Using the "wrong" direction:

```
rsync -vaN --delete --iconv=utf8,utf8-mac Mac_folder/ NAS_folder/
```

works as expected: one sync copy only and further syncs only when files change (although I got the impression that this option is obsolete and does nothing..)

**Sync direction is always Mac -> NAS!**

`NAS_folder` is mounted with Samba. MacOS is 12.6 on an M1 MacBook.

Comment: same here, for rsync to an exfat hard disk drive mounted to `/Volumes`.
Oddly enough though, when i omit the --iconv option, files whose names have a space in addition of the umlaut (say, `"König copie.txt"`), work ok!!  So rsync **does** know how to deal with the umlaut.  However if i add --iconv, then the `"König copie.txt"` is included in the repetition with other umlaut files…

Comment: So its probably best to leave the "wrong" --iconv option enabled. Fiddeling too  much with these optione even resulted in double file entries on the NAS only visible when you use the Synology File Explorer to identify them.   My impression is that rsync is too old and bloated for such a task. However so far I could not find an alternative sync software as powerful.